# Windows Store App TextBox issue with barcode reader

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, barcode-scanner

in my Windows universal app, i want scan some barcodes with a bluethoot barcode reader device.
Windows pair correctly the barcode device as an external keyboard and testing the device in Notepad or other windows text input it correctly works. I saw too thant the device send the single keystrokes.

Running a simple test app, in debug mode or release mode from Visual Studio to a remote device (Dell 10 Pro tablet in this case) , with a single TextBox the barcode present some problem.

If the first character of the scanned barcode is a number, only the first digit is printed on the textbox and the remaining digits are printed after tap everywhere in the screen.

I'm going crazy because this isn't a systematic error and is present only in my tablet device.

When the barcode is correctly scanned , the digits are printed slowly in the textbox of the test app, but the same barcode in the notepad the digits are printed fast.

This problem is also present with a Windows 8.1 test app.

Hope you can address me to a solution.